# How to select and check values of indiviual rows and add text to it data SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Ok so now i have a problem which is when i select the data from table i want to count data and select it

the data in this table consist of

```
| Name | Fruits |
| Ben  | Apple  |
| Tim  | Orange |
| Tim  | Pear   |
| Tim  | Grape  |
```

So here's how  want it to be viewed

```
| Name | Fruits Number         |
| Ben  | 1                     |
| Tim  | 3 Have too many fruits|
```

this is how i want it to show but when i run if else statement it show like this

```
| Name | Fruits Number         |
| Ben  | 1 Have too many fruits|            
| Tim  | 3 Have too many fruits|
```

Please help me with this simple problem

```
if((select count(fruits) from fruits_table )>1)(select name , (count(Fruits) + 'Have too many fruits') as'Fruits number' from Fruits Table group by Name)
else (select name , (count(Fruits) + ) as'Fruits number' from Fruits Table group by Name)
```

Comment: Show us your select statement, and some sample table data producing the result(s) specified.

Comment: If you got a problem with your else if statement you should include it in your code

Comment: What does the raw data look like?  What data type is `Fruits Number`?

Comment: OK just Edited it in

Comment: that's never going to work in mysql. `+` is mathematical addition. you're trying to concatenate, so you need the `concat()` function.

Comment: use `group by` clause

Comment: @Marc ok i've just looked it up so `concat()` is a code that make int values into string but that not what i am looking for i am looking for a way to dynamically detect the count value and add a text behind that specify row of data when selected

Comment: uh, no, concat joins strings together. `concat('foo', 42, 'bar')` will work only because the rest of mysql does (int)42 -> (string)42. `count(somefield) + 'some text'` is effectively `count(somefield) + 0`, unless that some text starts with a numerical value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Name, 
    CASE WHEN Count(*) > 2 THEN CONCAT(COUNT(*), ' Have too many fruits')  
         ELSE CAST(COUNT(*) As CHAR) 
    END AS 'Fruits Number'
FROM 
    MyTable Group By Name
```

In your fruits example a case should work.  Of course you can base it on a sub query and reduce the `COUNT()`'s

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER UPDATED**

```
SELECT 
    `Name`,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN CONCAT(COUNT(*), ' Have too many fruits')
        ELSE CAST(COUNT(*) AS CHAR)
    END AS 'Fruits Number'
FROM
    MyTable
GROUP BY `Name`
```

Use `concat` of mysql

[CONCAT](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat-function.php)

It can add strings
like this

```
SELECT CONCAT(1, ' test')
// 1 test
```

Comment: this error pop-up
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.

Comment: @Kenneth I just helped you how to use this `CONCAT()` not whole of Query

Comment: ok thanks! , but still i dont see a way of achieving what i want using `concat()` but its nice to know there's a function like this

Answer (score 0):

This does exactly what you asked for:

```
SELECT name, 
  IF (fruitcount > 1, 
      concat(fruitcount, ' Have too many fruits'), 
      cast(fruitcount as char)) AS 'Fruits number'
FROM (
  SELECT name, Count(*) as fruitcount
  FROM fruits_table
  GROUP BY Name
) AS z;
```

But this is probably a better way to do it, since it gives you a separate column for the "too many fruits" signal.

```
SELECT name, fruitcount, IF (fruitcount > 1, ' Yes',  '' ) as 'Too many?'
FROM (
  SELECT name, Count(*) as fruitcount
  FROM fruits_table
  GROUP BY Name
) AS z;
```